# "Unresolved reference: http" Kotlin. Why does this happen?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, kotlin

Here is where it fails.

The full error message looks like this:

```java
#12 55.48 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.5.30:compile (compile) on project tool: Compilation failure
#12 55.48 [ERROR] /workspace/app/src/main/kotlin/com/ob/tool/LoginController.kt:[7,17] Unresolved reference: http
```

Code:

```java
package com.ob.tool

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import java.net.http.HttpResponse

@RestController
class LoginController {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = ["http://localhost:8080"])
    @PostMapping("/login")
    fun login(@RequestBody user: User): ResponseEntity<Response> {
       return if(user.username == "Admin" && user.password == "Admin4040") ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK) else ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    }

}
```

My Dockerfile/docker-compose looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build
WORKDIR /workspace/app

COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src src

RUN ./mvnw install -DskipTests
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency && (cd target/dependency; jar -xf ../*.jar)

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=/workspace/app/target/dependency
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=build ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]
```

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/App/src

  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - ./backend/src:/App/src
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `java.net.http` package was introduced in Java 11 as far as I know, but you're using JDK8 in your docker image.

That being said, you don't seem to be using `java.net.http.HttpResponse` at all in the code, so you could just remove the import I believe.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. This is the answer.